# Mocking Settings (settings.php) within Unit tests

Tags: testing, 9

Drupal's `Settings` class is marked final and has no interface, meaning traditional PHPUnit mocking techniques will not work out of the box. Is it necessary to install third-party tools to be able to mock this or is there another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first glance `Settings` appears to be read-only, however the constructor is quite forgiving in its parameters. We can construct a fake settings structure like so:

```
$site_settings = [
  'http_services_api' => [
    'auth_services' => [
      'title' => 'Auth Services',
      'config' => [
        'base_uri' => 'https://demo.api-platform.com/auth'
      ],
    ],
    'resource_services' => [
      'title' => 'Resource Services',
      'config' => [
        'base_uri' => 'https://demo.api-platform.com/books'
      ],
    ],
  ],
];

new Settings($site_settings);
```

This is alluded too [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/testing/phpunit-in-drupal/unit-testing-more-complicated-drupal-classes#s-mocking-values-in-the-settingsphp-during-tests) but never fully described.

Edit: I have added an example to the docs linked.